# Making a viewmodel error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, viewmodel

I am making a viewmodel for the first time, after some research I got the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HotelWPF
{
    public class ReservationVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
        private string SecretaryName;
        private int RoomNumber;
        private string ReservationType;
        private DateTime ReservationDate;

        public string SecretaryName1
        {
            get
            {
                return SecretaryName;
            }

            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref SecretaryName, value);
            }
        }

        public int RoomNumber1
        {
            get
            {
                return RoomNumber;
            }

            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref RoomNumber, value);
            }
        }

        public string ReservationType1
        {
            get
            {
                return ReservationType;
            }

            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref ReservationType, value);
            }
        }

        public DateTime ReservationDate1
        {
            get
            {
                return ReservationDate;
            }

            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref ReservationDate, value);
            }
        }
        public void SetProperty<T>(ref T store, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            store = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedArgs(name));

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
PropertyChanged doesn't exist in current context.
```

also CallerMemberName gives me an error:

```
Type or namespace couldn't be found
```

It's pretty hard to make a viewmodel as a first year student, help will be appreciated

Edit:
This is one of my model classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HotelWPF
{
   public class Reservation
    {
        private string SecretaryName;
        private int RoomNumber;
        private string ReservationType;
        private DateTime ReservationDate;

        public string SecretaryName1
        {
            get
            {
                return SecretaryName;
            }

            set
            {
                SecretaryName = value;
            }
        }

        public int RoomNumber1
        {
            get
            {
                return RoomNumber;
            }

            set
            {
                RoomNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public string ReservationType1
        {
            get
            {
                return ReservationType;
            }

            set
            {
                ReservationType = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime ReservationDate1
        {
            get
            {
                return ReservationDate;
            }

            set
            {
                ReservationDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't actually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`; you just promised the compiler that you would in the class declaration, here:

```
ReservationVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

And now it's holding you to that promise. To implement that particular interface, you just need to implement the `PropertyChanged` event in your viewmodel class, `ReservationVM`. That's easy, just add this line that defines it:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Visual Studio will implement interfaces for you, too. Right click on the interface name in the class declaration up top, and choose "Implement Interface" off the context menu (depending on VS version, that may be under "Quick Actions and Refactorings" instead). You don't want to implement "explicitly", just regular "implement".

Once that's there, then you need the namespace for `CallerMemberNameAttribute`. That's a quick one too:

Add this line:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

...to the top of the file.

Another point I'd like to make is with the naming of your properties. It's not going to break anything, but the public/private naming convention you came up with isn't a good idea. This is the more usual convention:

```
    private string _secretaryName;
    public string SecretaryName
    {
        get
        {
            return _secretaryName;
        }

        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _secretaryName, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: to the viewmodel or model class?

Comment: @Gigitex Viewmodel. The one that says it's implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Gigitex Can you paste the new version of the code in your question?

Comment: @Gigitex That should be `PropertyChangedEventArgs`, not `PropertyChangedArgs`

Comment: That problem is solved, but 'Quick actions and refactorings' did this to my code:  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));   
instead of the previous code

Comment: @Gigitex That code is actually the correct implementation (thread-safe, yours isn't)

Comment: @Gigitex That `?.Invoke` stuff is good! If nobody is handling your `PropertyChanged` event, then `PropertyChanged(this, args)` will throw a null reference exception. `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, ...)` skips the call if there's no handlers.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Hope that the rest will work out too :P

Comment: what does this code actually do? If I add buttons to it, will it work then?

Comment: What it does is that if you bind the public viewmodel properties to control properties in XAML, then when you change the viewmodel properties, the XAML controls will be notified and they'll update themselves accordingly. Let me add one more bit to my answer, because I see something unwise in your viewmodel.

Comment: Visual Studio calls them automaticly like that, I don't know why

Comment: Do you have skype or something for If I have a small question?

Comment: No, I don't have Skype. Are you creating them with a snippet or something?

Comment: I am using quick refactorings to add those setters

Comment: Ah, OK, VS 2012 does that with "Encapsulate Field". Yeah, I wouldn't use that.

Comment: @Gigitex If you're feeling ambitious, you could figure out how to install VS snippets, and rewrite the `inot` snippet here to use your `SetProperty<T>`: https://swissarmycrowbar.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/viewmodel-property-snippets-c6/

Answer (score 2):

`PropertyChanged` is an event that is required to be defined by `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The *easiest* way to get it is to use the "Implement interface" suggestion by putting the input cursor on `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your code and pressing `Ctrl+.` You can also hover over it with your mouse, then click the lightbulb that appears.

Or just add the following line to your view model:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Your other error is because you haven't added the namespace for `CallerMemberName`. You can get it from the "using" suggestion the same way as above or add the following line to the top of your view model file:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```